# Delete certain django app from a django project on heroku and exclude it from future push

Tags: django, heroku

In my django project named `website` I have two apps `app1` & `app2` . I want to keep `app2` accessible only through my local machine. I dont want `app2` to be publicly accessible online through my website. I have already pushed my entire `website` to heroku. So how can I delete `app2` from heroku `website` and avoid pushing `app2` to heroku in future.

I have tried following things:

1. Added `app2/` to `.gitignore`. So future changes are avoided. But current version of `app2` still exist on heroku `website`.
2. I deleted `app2` on local machine and tried to push the changes, but I got error in static collection saying no app named `app2` exists.

I would also like to avoid having Django's default admin functionality available through my website. I would like to keep it local too. 
Thanks

Comment: "Added `app2/` to `.gitignore`. So future changes are avoided." That's not how Git's ignore system works. It can prevent things from being tracked but has no effect on files that are already being tracked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep both apps under version control, then control the differences through settings. For example, if you only have DEBUG set locally:

*settings.py*

```py
if settings.DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['app2']
```

*urls.py*

```py
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        include('app2/', include('app2.urls')),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

This is just an example, without knowing more about your project, it is hard to show exactly how to do it. But with this example, `app2` would only be loaded and have routes available when the `DEBUG` setting was `True`.